# Test that an argument to a method has been changed

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit.net

I'm trying to write some tests using xUnit and Moq and I can't seem to wrap my head around how to test that an argument provided to a method has been changed by the method itself.

Here's what I have:

```cs
[Fact]
public void WhenCreateAsyncCalledSomePropertyIsSet()
{
    // Arrange
    var mockSomeService = new Mock<ISomeService>();
    var someObject = new SomeObject();

    // Act
    mockSomeService.Setup(x => x.CreateAsync(someObject)).Callback(() => {
        someObject.SomeProperty = "SomeValue";
    });

    // Assert
    Assert.NotNull(someObject.SomeProperty);
}
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is make sure that when the `CreateAsync(someObject)` is called it sets the `SomeProperty` property of the `someObject` argument. My test fails..

UPDATE:

I'm trying to test the following method:

```cs
public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    private readonly SomeContext _context;

    public SomeService(SomeContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task CreateAsync(SomeObject someObject)
    {
        someObject.SomeProperty = GenerateRandomString();

        _context.SomeObjects.Add(project);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

I want to test whether `SomeProperty` is set (like above) when the method is called. If I forget to set it I want the test to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service is tightly coupled to the `SomeContext` implementation concern. Unless you plan to do in-memory testing that context is going to cause some complications.

Abstract the context.

```
public interface ISomeContext {
    ISomeSet<SomeObject> SomeObjects { get; set; }
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(); 
}
```

The class would refactor so that it no longer depended on implementation concerns and allow for greater flexibility.

```
public class SomeService : ISomeService {
    private readonly ISomeContext _context;

    public SomeService(ISomeContext context) {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task CreateAsync(SomeObject someObject) {
        someObject.SomeProperty = GenerateRandomString();    
        _context.SomeObjects.Add(project);    
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    string GenerateRandomString() {
        //...other code
    }
}
```

And the test would mock the functionality of the dependencies of that subject under test and inject it when exercising the test.

```
public Task WhenCreateAsyncCalledSomePropertyIsSet() {
    // Arrange
    var mockSomeContext = new Mock<ISomeContext>();
    mockSomeContext
        .Setup(x => x.SaveChangesAsync())
        .ReturnsAsync(1); //Because the method under test is async

    var sut = new SomeService (mockSomeContext.Object); //Actual service, fake context
    var someObject = new SomeObject(); //actual object

    Assert.IsNull(someObject.SomeProperty); //making sure it was null to begin with

    // Act
    await sut.CreateAsync(someObject); //call method under test.
    var actual = someObject.SomeProperty; //get the value

    // Assert
    Assert.NotNull(actual); //Assert that it was actually set.
}
```

Your real context would be derived from the abstraction/interface or wrapped by something that provides that functionality.

Review [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of the framework.